# How to align horizontally a multiline CLI help text with OptionParser

Tags: ruby, rubygems, command-line-interface

I am trying to make the output of my CLI Ruby gem `my_command --help` cleaner.

There is some CLI options and flags that need a couple of sentences to explain them. I don't have found a way to properly align this text in their column when the explanation is too long to fit inside a regular terminal width view.

I want to have something like this:

[image: ab --help as an example]
*ab --help as an example, note how some flags have a multiple line explanations with a proper alignment.*

Right now, I am doing something like this in OptionParser to keep text aligned in their column in case we need multiple lines to explain something:

```
opts.on("-d", "--directory PATH", String, "Directory to save the downloaded files into\n\t\t\t\t     Default is ./websites/ plus the domain name") do |t|
  options[:directory] = t
end
```

It's working, but it doesn't seem optimal nor clean to have `\t` everywhere to force formatting. Plus, I can see cases where it's not being formatted correctly in other terminal configurations.

How can I align horizontally a multiline CLI help text with OptionParser in a clean way?

Comment: The gem with the issue for ref: https://github.com/hartator/wayback-machine-downloader

Comment: Well, couldn't test but I would start looking by here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html#method-i-summarize, with the `indent` and `width` options maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force line breaks without needing to add tabs by adding more parameters to `opts.on`:

```
opts.on("-d", "--directory PATH", String, 
        "Directory to save the downloaded files into",
        "Default is ./websites/ plus the domain name") do |t|
  options[:directory] = t
end
```

This isn't very clearly documented in official documentation, but you can see it used in the [complete example](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/OptionParser.html#class-OptionParser-label-Complete+example).